# graph conversion - what is the name of it?

Tags: graph, terminology, graph-theory, transformation

I have a graph and here's a part of it (nodes are located at the intersections of edges; the outer rectangle is not part of the graph):

[image]

I want to convert its faces into vertices like this:

[image]

And then draw edges between the new vertices and discard the original image:

[image]

What is the name of this conversion?

Thanks for your patience; it's been a while since I took graph theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the [centroid of each polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon) (face) using the coordinates of its old vertices, and use them as the new vertices. By connecting the new vertices the way you show in the third figure, you get a [dual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of the original graph.

Comment: it's an example, of course it's just path of a graph and I don't show the vertices because they're at the intersection of edges

Comment: I know how, I just want to know what it is called ;)